# Am I safe after importing Bitdefender's fake certificate?

Tags: certificates, firefox

I installed Bitdefender today and suddenly I couln't navigate to numerous websites that I used to visit (I use Mozilla Firefox). I got the error: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER.

I searched a bit and found [this](https://support.mozilla.org/el/questions/1238264) solution which suggested to import a fake certificate located in Bitdefender's installation folder to Firefox.

What impact will this fake certificate have on my PC's security?

Comment: I woudn't suggest to install a fake SSL Certificate. This fault also often comes when you use a proxy or such things which want to intercept your SSL trafic to prevent you from downloading malware or do other bad things. Are you behind a proxy? Is this happening on different networks? Try using your phone connection for testing. Are you sure that the problem is Bitdefender?

Comment: @CDRohling The problem is definitely bitdefender. I am not behind a proxy and I use the same computer for years ( I used to have Avast antivirus) and started happening as soon as I installed Bitdefender

Comment: Are you able to select: "Do not scan encrypted connections" in bitdefender? -> https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/common-bitdefender-issues/. If this will work the Problem will solve without installing a fake certificate on your pc and the endpoint protection makes the rest

Comment: @CDRohling I suppose that this would be available in the paid version? Because the free version that I am using doesn't let you do this..

Answer (score 1):

Bitdefender web protection is validating the certificate before reaches your browser but the certificate root itself is modified/removed/replaced by agent before sent to browser.

Now a days the browser(firefox/chrome) itself is also validating the certificate, as the certificate root/chain is modified/replaced by the one from bitdefender agent, this re-validation process by browser fail : The certificate root in chain is not signed by known agency. (Bitdefender is not the agency which issues the certificate.)

If you trust the Agent like bitdefender/avast then you can import their face/temp certificate into your browser so that browser can trust the certificate signed by them.

This avoids the browser throwing the certificate error next time.